# Creating one Profile for user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, associations

I'm trying to create a user profile that will have skills, educations, experiences, languages, ... so for this i have this relation

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  after_create :create_profile

  private 

  def create_profile
    Profile.create(user: self)
  end   
end



 class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

        belongs_to :user

        has_many :profile_languages, dependent: :destroy
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile_languages , :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:language_name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
        has_many :profile_skills, dependent: :destroy
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile_skills , :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:skill_name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

    end
```

but the problem is after sign up and go to edit the profile the languages and skills will not be saved

this is my profiles controller

```
def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.profile  
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.profile


    if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
      redirect_to profile_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = @profile.errors.full_messages
      redirect_to edit_profile_path
    end
  end

private

def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:user_id, :summary, :profile_title, :useravatar, :profile_skills_attributes: [:id, :skill_name,:_destroy], profile_languages_attributes: [:id, :language, :proficiency, :_destroy] )
    end
```

I was thinking to add a new class in profile controller that will be like this

```
  def new
    @profile = current_user.profile.build
    @profile.profile_languages.build
    @profile.profile_skills.build
  end
```

but i don't think this would be a good solution because i'm already creating the profile after sign up, so i'm wondering what would be the better solution for this

Update

```
 <%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
..................
      <%= render 'profile_language_fields', f: f %>
      <%= link_to_add_fields "Add languages", f, :profile_languages %>
<%= end  %>
```

and this is profile_language partial

```
<%= f.fields_for :profile_languages do |pl| %>
        <div class="plform-group">
            <div class="form-planguage-half">
              <%= pl.text_field :language, class: 'form-control form-two-half'  %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-planguage-half-last">
              <%= pl.select(:proficiency, [
                      ["Débutant", 1], 
                      ["Intermédiaire", 2], 
                      ["Courant", 3], 
                      ["Bilingue", 4], 
                      ["Natif", 5]], 
                      {}, {class: "form-control form-two-half"}) %>
            </div>
    <%= pl.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you please post your edit profile form

Comment: See the edit form in update

Comment: you want after signup the profile and its profille_languages & skills should be save automatically. right?

Comment: after sign up the profile is created what i want is when go to do edit and add a language or/and skills it must be saved

Comment: have you added the following code in edit and tried to save ?  ` @profile.profile_languages.build @profile.profile_skills.build `

Comment: I have tried this and it is working but is it a good solution because every time i go to profile edit page a blank profile languages and skills field is added

Comment: it is because in ` after_save `  you are just creating an profile. if u create profile_launguage & skill there then it will not add blank fields.